# Wordpress: List page of custom post type in wp-admin return "Allowed memory size Error"

Tags: php, wordpress, out-of-memory

I had a error of `"Allowed memory size"` in list page of custom post type.
It was solved by adding more memory of php.

`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=products`

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1858

It is strange because this problem does not occur with other list page with different custom post type.

I checked debug backtrace.
The products list has approximately `5000` record.

query_posts method get all products's record from database.
query_string is

```
 "order=asc&orderby=menu_order%20title&post_type=products&posts_per_page=-1&posts_per_archive_page=-1 "
```

I think that this problem occurred by getting all records as wp object.

My question is:
Is there a way to display this list page without getting all records?
Is there anything wrong with my wordpress setting?

Thanx for helping.

Comment: `posts_per_page=-1` and `posts_per_archive_page=-1` probably is interpreted as "all available". Fill in values that make sense, I suggest.

Comment: it's probably infinite loop

Comment: Thank you for advice.
I set "posts_per_page=20". but It did not change anything.
I also tried "posts_per_archive_page=20". then, the pager disappeared and the number of total lists become 20, at least it was shown 20.

Comment: I did little more research on this.It seems the cause of my condtion is below.WP_Posts_List_Table class is used in "/wp-admin/edit.php".
set_pagination_args is init method for web pager.set_pagination_args method of WP_Posts_List_Table is called with total_items.And it is $wp_query->post_count because hierarchical = true and default orderby.
post_count is count value of array of acquired record in WP_Query.wordpress may get all record when hierarchical = true and default orderby.This problem did not occurred when orderby=title.Is there anything I can do to the other ?Thanx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved.
When opening wp-admin/edit.php of hierarchical custom post type, wordpress get all records.
So I set hierarchical=false in setting of custom post type.
We didn't need hierarchical=true in setting of custom post type.